# Show that $g(x)$ is continuous at 0.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, proof-writing

Let $g(x)= \begin{cases} 
e^{-1/x^2} & x\neq0 \\
0 & x=0 \\
\end{cases}$

Additionally, show that $g(x)$ is differentiable for all $x\in\mathbb R$ with $g'(0)=0$.

Comment: Do you know what it means for a function to be continuous at a point?

Comment: This is a well known example of a function that is infinitely differentiable at the origin where all derivatives vanish. As such, the Taylor Series converges nowhere but at $x=0$ and is constant regardless of how many terms of the Taylor Series we take, even though our original function is smooth, not a second degree polynomial, and non-zero

Answer (score 2):

**HINT**

To show it's continuous at zero you need to show that $$\lim_{x\to 0}g(x) = \lim_{x\to 0 } e^{-1/x^2}=g(0) = 0.$$

To show it's differentiable at zero you must show that $$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{g(x)-g(0)}{x} = \lim_{x\to 0}  \frac{e^{-1/x^2}}{x}$$ exists. (And that it equals $0$ in order to show $g'(0) = 0.$)